# C++ get directory prefix

Tags: c++, string, directory

For example I have the string `"root/data/home/file1.txt"`  I would like to get `"root/data/home"` Is there a convenient function in C++ that allows me to do this or should I code it myself?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do basic string manipulation, i.e.

```
std::string path = "root/data/home/file1.txt";
// no error checking here
std::string prefix = path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/'));
```

or take a third option like [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm):

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path path = "root/data/home/file1.txt";
fs::path prefix = path.parent_path();
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning boost, which will work with different platforms

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a POSIX system, try [dirname(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname).

Answer (score 2):

There's certainly no convenient function in the language itself.  The string library provides [find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/), which should do well.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather platform-dependent.  For example, Windows uses `'\'` for a path separator (mostly), Unix uses `'/'`, and MacOS (prior to OSX) uses `':'`.

The Windows-specific API is `PathRemoveFileSpec`.